# Creating iPhone 5 screenshots

Tags: iphone, ios6, screenshot

I've installed the latest xcode version and tested my app with the 6.0 simulator, etc. How do I go about creating the required iPhone 5 screenshots, since I have the 4s and not an iphone 5 device to connect with?

Comment: Why not take it within the simulator itself?

Comment: I tried and the dimensions seem to be the same as old iphone and iPad and not at the 640x1136,etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can take screenshots from the simulator. You have to change the device in the simulator options to get the larger screen size.

Change the device:
Hardware>Device>iPhone(Retina 4-inch)

You can scale it down with:
Window>Scale

Answer (score 8):

Change the device: Hardware>Device>iPhone(Retina 4-inch)

Press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>

Screenshot will automatically come on your desktop

Answer (score 3):

Run Your app in simulator(Any,according to what you need)

When you want a screenshot

Press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>

Or

File -> Save Screenshot

It saves the screenshot on the desktop(default)